# How can i raise the wall in unity3d once and control the raising speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The part with touching the object and playing the animation is working fine now i want to add the walls script part.

In this case i change a cube height.
What i need to do is that only when the player touch an object it will raise/change the height of another object.

Son in the first case i find when the player is touching an object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;
    int counter = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "ThirdPersonController") // "Platform"
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "ThirdPersonController") // "OnTop Detector"
        {
            counter = 0;
            Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
            GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;

            GameObject go = GameObject.Find("CubeToRaise");
            go.GetComponent<RaiseWalls>();
            Debug.Log("The button clicked, raising the wall");

            StartCoroutine(playAnim(target));
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        findGo.transform.parent = null;
    }

    IEnumerator playAnim(GameObject target)
    {
        Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();

        foreach (AnimationState clip in anim)
        {
            // do initialisation or something on clip
            clip.speed = 1;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (counter == 1)
                break;
            anim.Play("Up");

            while (anim.IsPlaying("Up"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            anim.Play("Down");

            while (anim.IsPlaying("Down"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            yield return null;

            counter++;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20),
            "Times lift moved up and down " + counter);
    }
}
```

At this part i'm calling the second script RaiseWalls:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RaiseWalls : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject gameObjectToRaise;
    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 2;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        gameObjectToRaise.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 50, 0);
    }


}


GameObject go = GameObject.Find("CubeToRaise");
go.GetComponent<RaiseWalls>();
Debug.Log("The button clicked, raising the wall");
```

Now the DetectPlayer is attached on one game object.
The RaiseWalls script is attached on another game object.

On the RaiseWalls script i want to set the speed of the object height change. Now it's changing the height by 50 but many times. I want it to change it by 50 but in slow motion like a slowly building/raising wall. Like electronic fence that raise from bottom to top effect.

Second problem i want that first it will raise the wall or walls once it finished raising the walls move to the next part in the DetectPlayer script:

```
StartCoroutine(playAnim(target));
```

Steps:

1. When the player is touching the object in DetectPlayer script raise the wall/s in RaiseWalls script in specific speed.
2. When the walls raised only then make the StartCoroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to raise the wall 50 in total, but with a controllable speed.

First make a counter in RaiseWalls:

```
float raiseAmount;
```

Also record the total to raise it, which makes it easier to change later:

```
float raiseTotal = 50;
```

Then, in your Update, raise it by a little, but record how much was raised

```
if(raiseAmount < raiseTotal ) // i.e. we haven't raised it fully
{
    // work out how much to raise it
    float raiseThisFrame = speed * Time.DeltaTime; // to account for frame rate
    // now we cap it to make sure it doesn't go over 50
    if(raiseAmount + raiseThisFrame > raiseTotal )
    {
        raiseThisFrame = raiseTotal - raiseAmount;
    }

    // add raiseThisFrame to raiseAmount
    raiseAmount += raiseThisFrame;

    gameObjectToRaise.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, raiseThisFrame, 0);
}
```